# How to Add Customizer Setting in Child Theme

Tags: customization, child-theme, theme-customizer, parent-theme, characters

I would like to add an option to the Customizer of my Child Theme, but I am having some trouble implementing it. I am pretty sure my problem is connected to the name of the arguments I am calling, but I'm not sure, so if you see something else, please do not hesitate to tell me what you think.

#### What I suspect is wrong:

1. I am unsure what arguments in my `functions.php` should have child theme's name (e.g. `child_theme_name`/ `tesseract-child`), and the parent theme's title (e.g. `parent_theme_name`/`tesseract`) . Normally I would assume I should always use the child theme's name, but the declaration for the panels the Parent theme's `customizer.php` file includes the Parent theme's name (`tesseract_footer_options`), and I'm unsure if WordPress modifies that name when using child themes.  For example, should the first argument in `add_section` in a Child theme's  be `parent_theme_name_footer_options` or `child_theme_name_footer_options`
2. If I am supposed to use a child theme's name, I am confused how to. When I try to name the function with a reference to the child theme's name (e.g. `tesseract-child_options`), which includes hyphens, I get an error. So, I don't think php likes to have functions that are named with hyphens, and in fact I have read that this php doesn't allow hyphen in function names. Another clue that hyphens are bad: not only did the hyphens from the child theme name cause a crash, it caused my editor (sublime text) to markup the code strangely. To test if hyphens were the problem, I changed the name of the function to `tesseract_child_options`, using all underscores, but that seems wrong to me, because technically the theme's name is `tesseract-child` with a hyphen, not `tesseract_child` with an underscore.

#### The Code

This is the declaration of the panel in the Parent Theme's `customizer.php` file:

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'tesseract_footer_options', array(

'priority'       => 5,

'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',

'title'          => 'Footer Options',

//'description'  => ''

) );
```

This is the the code I am using in my Child Theme's `function.php` file to try to add a section to that Options Panel:

```
add_action( 'customize_register' , 'tesseract_child_options' );

function tesseract_child_options( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_section( 
    'tesseract_footer_options', 
    array(
        'title'       => __( 'Reblog Options', 'tesseract' ),
        'priority'    => 100,
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'description' => __('Change Reblog Options Here.', 'tesseract'), 
    ) 
);


$wp_customize->add_setting( 'number_of_reblogs',
    array(
        'default' => '3'
    )
);  

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( 
    $wp_customize, 
    'reblog_number_control',
    array(
        'label'    => __( 'Number of Reblogs', 'tesseract-child' ), 
        'section'  => 'tesseract_footer_options',
        'settings' => 'reblog_number',
        'type'     => 'text',
        'priority' => 10,
    ) 
));

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

### UPDATE REGARDING PROSTI'S ANSWER:

@Prosti answered the question, but I just want to clarify what was wrong for anyone who is trying to figure out how to do this:

1. The name of the entire function called by the action `customize_register` is arbitrary, you can name it anything you want, as long as you don't include hyphens. Note that this function name **does not** have to relate to the parent theme's name or the child theme's name in any way. To illustrate this, in my working example (shown below), I changed the function name I used in my initial question from `tesseract_child_options` to `childtheme_customize_register`. *Please note that while you don't have to reference the child theme or parent theme's name in this function, it is nonetheless good practice to, but just for the sake of legibility, not functionality.*
2. The name of the section you are creating (the first argument in function `add_section`) is arbitrary, you can name it anything you want. That is a tag that WP will use for internal passing of the variable. The text you include int he second argument of `add_section` will determine what text appears when you first land on the root menu of the customizer (the first menu that appears). *Again, good practice dictates that for legibility purposes use a name connected to the theme.*
3. Inside the `add_section`, and `add_control` functions, all of the two argument statements I used (e.g. `title`, `description`, and `label`) needed to have the exact name of the child theme as the second argument. If that child theme's name has hyphens (as was the case with mine, e.g. `tesseract-child`), this second argument should also have hyphens.
4. The `priority` of the section determined where (i.e how high or low) the section I created fell inside of the options list. The footer was 4th section in the parent them and it had a priority of `5`. If I set the priority inside of of `add_section`, to have a priority of `4` the option came above the footer option button, if I set it to `6`, it fell below it.

### Example of Working Code

```
 
add_action( 'customize_register', 'childtheme_customize_register'); //second argument is arbitrary, but cannot have hyphens because php does not allow them in function names.



function childtheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_section( 
    'tesseract_reblog_options', 
    array(
        'title'       => __( 'Reblog Options', 'tesseract-child' ), //2nd arg matches child theme name 
        'priority'    => 6, // put the section below the Footer options on the list
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'description' => __('Change Reblog Options Here.', 'tesseract-child'), //2nd arg matches child theme name 
    ) 
);


$wp_customize->add_setting( 'number_of_reblogs',
    array(
        'default' => '3'
    )
);  

$wp_customize->add_control( 'setting_id', array(
  'label'    => __( 'Number of Reblogs', 'tesseract-child' ), //2nd arg matches child theme name
    'section'  => 'tesseract_reblog_options',
    'settings' => 'number_of_reblogs',
    'type'     => 'text',
    'priority' => 6
) );
}
```

Comment: if your setting is `number_of_reblogs` you need to have  `'settings' => 'number_of_reblogs',` in your control.

Comment: also you don't need to create a custom control. So no need for `new WP_Customize_Control` when `$wp_customize->add_control`

Comment: Do I delete the whole section following `$wp_customize->add_control`?

Comment: do you at least have the control appearing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, check out the theme developer [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/).

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'reblog_number_control', array(
  'label'    => __( 'Number of Reblogs', 'tesseract-child' ), 
    'section'  => 'tesseract_footer_options',
    'settings' => 'number_of_reblogs',
    'type'     => 'text',
    'priority' => 10
) );
```

Since you are in the child theme

```
'title'       => __( 'Reblog Options', 'tesseract' ),
```

shoudl be

```
'title'       => __( 'Reblog Options', 'tesseract-child' ),
```

In other words, your setting, control and section names need to match in `add_control`, `add_section`, `add_setting`.

Comment: It still isn't working, the priority of the parent panel is 5, what should the priorities be for the containing function, the child section, the child setting, and the child control? I believe greater than five/lower than 5, so they run later, but should they be the same (e.g. 6, 6, 6) or differ from each (e.g. 6,7, 8).

Comment: Does the name of the function called by the action have to have a certain syntax regarding the theme (e.g. `tesseract_child_options`), or can it be anything?

Comment: @CoderScissorhands, if you have only a single control in a section priorities are not important.

Comment: @CoderScissorhands, the name of the function `tesseract_child_options` is just fine.

Comment: there are four other existing sections from the parent theme in the panel. Does that change what you say about priority not mattering?

Comment: Uau, I have exactly 888 points now, Hallelujah. Thanks @CoderScissorhands